# Java Flash AS3 socket reading larger packets + code confirmation

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, sockets

So I read around and apparently the network breaks up packets into smaller chunks or something and sends them separately but java does not know what is the total size of bytes that should be received. I added a bytesize prefix to the packet so it knows how much to read

```
while ( inputStream.available() != -1 )
        {
            int packetSize = inputStream.readByte() ;

            if ( packetSize == -1 )
            {
                closeConnection();
            }

            debug( "read bytearray size:" + packetSize );
            ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte packetBuffer[] = new byte[packetSize];
            int byteTrans = 0;
            while ( byteTrans < packetSize )
            {inputStream.read() );
                inputStream.read( packetBuffer , byteTrans , 1 );
                byteTrans++;
            }
```

I tried playing around with read, and so far this is what I've gotten to work.

I think I remember that a byte can only contain and int up to 255. I think I should send an unsigned short instead for those large strings?

My main question is : is the same thing true for flash actionscript 3?
If so, how do I implement something similar?

The idea I have is in the handler for socketData, read the buffer size, then save all the data onto a bytearray buffer on the class. if the size of the buffer is the received size, then run the reading method. So in general, running the code in the while loop on the java side each time the socketData handler is called.

Thanks!

Comment: When sending data you should end your packet with a null character. you can "flush" the buffer at any time and on the receiving end just store the data in a var until that null character is read. So basically you store the data and add to it until the null. Once you get that null you process it.

Comment: the inputstream error is a mistake pasting the code here.
I'm just using signed integers for now and I've implemented my idea in as3. Not sure if it works for bigger packets yet, as I haven't found a way to test it yet.

Comment: I believe the packet size will ultimately be determined by the MTU setting on the routers and other network hardware that will ultimately transmit the data.  If you check out the OSI 7 layer cake (model), also the greatest MTU on Ethernet is 1500 bytes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit.  Ultimately your data will be split into packets of this size and if sent using TCP will be marked with a sequence number and sent to be potentially received out of sequence then re-stitched based on the sequence num. With UDP order is disregarded, Ethernet standard and MTU still apply.

Comment: With regard to transmitting data efficiently using AS3 and Java I think AMF (BlazeDS) is really the way to go (you can do custom serialization to some degree if need be using Externalizable and IExternalizable), if you need a video streaming or audio streaming solution probably check out Red5.  If you're just experimenting to understand how the low level stuff works just stick with Java (also get Wireshark to see what's really going on).